# Laravel queue jobs with attempts, correct way to trigger new attempt?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to figure out what the correct way to do this is.

```
public $tries = 10;

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(){
    $result_of_some_logic = false;
    if($result_of_some_logic){
        // for the purpose of this example, we're all done here.
    } else{
        // we need to retry 10 minutes from now. how to trigger this attempt, and this attempt only!, to fail? 
    }
}
```

I read the laravel documentation but it just isn't clear to me what the correct way to do this is. I noticed that if I create a php error (for instance throw new whateverisnotdeclaredinnamespace()) the job attempt will fail, the worker will retry until the amount of $tries have exceeded. This is pretty much the behavior I want but I obviously want a clean code solution.

So to summarise: in Laravel 5.8 what is the correct way to "mark" the attempt to have failed in the handle() function?

Comment: Could you clarify why you don't want to use an exception?

Comment: Because it causes massive stack trace logs in the laravel log, and most of the time the "exception" is just that the third party requires me to wait before I can submit another request to their API. I'd like to gracefully see the attempt amounts rise until the max amount of tries have passed, then escalate to an exception and make the failed() method retrieve the exception message and send a notification email.

Answer (score 2):

You could try releasing the job back to the queue with a delay:

```
$this->release($delayInSeconds);
```

Comment: This would require me to manually test if the amount of attempts are >= $tries to decide if I should release() or to throw an exception. Which feels like coding against laravel's principles. But I'm new to Laravel so maybe I just don't see things clearly.

Comment: it would have failed already if it was hitting the attempt limit

Comment: To be clear, does `release()` increase the number of attempts, tries or both?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use failed function to handle Your error?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Exception;
use App\Podcast;
use App\AudioProcessor;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $podcast;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  Podcast  $podcast
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Podcast $podcast)
    {
        $this->podcast = $podcast;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @param  AudioProcessor  $processor
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(AudioProcessor $processor)
    {
        // Process uploaded podcast...
    }

    /**
     * The job failed to process.
     *
     * @param  Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        // Send user notification of failure, etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I do use the failed method, but I'd like to know how to gracefully make the handle() method cause a re-attempt. 

Now I'm using throw new \Exception('lorem ipsum...'), which generates a lot of log file lines on each attempt. I'd like to limit that.

Comment: The only way I see is to dispatch job again (in current job) rather then throwing Exception. If You have problem with log space you should configure Logging only for jobs, eg. by making specyfic .env for queues.